# Maven - testing stucks before the end on Windows 7

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Building project on Win7 takes huge ammout of time, especially leaving the test suite. On my windows machine for 172 tests it takes 230 seconds, and on Jenkins (Ubuntu) about 19 seconds.

I run maven with -X argument to see what it is hanging on, but none of error appeard, after that time it just goes to run next plugin.

I tried to speed up it with setting surefire plugin to run on 4 threads, but it is not the case - Jenkins has exactly the same project as me.

I found that sometimes it hangs on calling externall processes, but the projects is not calling any externall processes (what would be even so easy according to run it on two different OS).

When I run the tests one by one in Win7 the working time is definitly lower that runing them with whole rebuild. This behaviour is the same on other Win7 machines.

How can I figure out what is keeping the maven from leaving the tests and going to next step?

Windows 7 output

```
Last test output
<--- stucks here
Tests run: 172, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 230.682 sec - in TestSuite
Results :
Tests run: 172, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Next plugin run
```

Ubuntu output

```
Last test output    
Tests run: 172, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 18.954 sec - in TestSuite
Results :
Tests run: 172, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
Next plugin run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the surefire plugin version to the latest one 2.19, from 2.16 helped. Now on Windows 7 it takes about 12 seconds, but still I have no idea what was the original cause of stucking.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand what is going on in your OS, you have to somehow debug your OS. I recommend taking a look at [Microsoft Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb842062) and try to use Procmon (Process Monitor) and see what is going on. 
Sadly, it won't get you all the syscalls as `strace` on Linux does, but it might help you understand more what is going on.

You can also [debug your JVM that executes the tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html), it might also give you some answers.